# What will happen to the reading if the "A-connector" is grounded in an incremental encoder?

Tags: sensor, encoder

I have a machine, that the reading is around 50% of expectation. I guess maybe the "A-connector" is grounded accidentally during it is made. However, I cannot reach the wire.

I don't have an extra encoder to do the testing. Does anyone able to come up the answer base on theory?

I saw wiki a table in Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder. It should how to do the counting, but it does not say what if come count is skipped.

Comment: By "A-connector", do you mean one of the signal lines from your encoder?  Could you post a part number of your encoder or a link to its datasheet?

Comment: What I mean is the signal line of 'A pulse'. To make it more clear, I mean that A-connector is the connector that connect to 'A-pulse line' . There are two pulse lines in an incremental encoder (A pulse line and B pulse line). I am sorry that I did not say it clearly

Comment: Do you want to measure the speed only, or do you need the direction also?

Comment: Ok, then you need only oone pin. If you want to encrease the resolution, you can measure with falling and rising edge of the pin.

Comment: btw: how did you conclude that it was reading only the 50%? Try seperatly both pins.

Comment: It won't function. Fix the bad line A. Measure voltage , resistance and report back.

Comment: Actually we are making a machine for a customer who brings his only encoder and software. He also put down the old machine, so we have something to verify. The point is that the reading from the new machine is roughly half of the old machine. Some technicians in my company asked me for help. I saw that there was 'miswiring' in the new encoder. Note: I am not 100% sure whether it is miswiring or those technicians fixed it even they switched two wires. Therefore, I want to see what will happen of the reading if it is really miswiring of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what type of encoder and on what is decoding the encoder outputs.

If you grounded one of the outputs of a quadrature encoder and then connected it to a quadrature decoder, the decoder would think that the encoder is oscillating back and forth between two encoder 'ticks' instead of rotating.

If you grounded one of the outputs of an absolute encoder, the decoder would read the encoder as rotating but making sudden jumps periodically depending on what bit was shorted out.